# Delphi XE - unable to delete an item from system menu

Tags: c++, c, delphi, winapi, menuitem

I have the following code, which is adding items to the system menu. My problem is that DeleteMenu(SysMenu, cLANGMENU, MF_BYCOMMAND) is not deleting the pop-up menu added to system menu. What I can not understand is why is working for the items (Scan components) added, but not for the 'Program Language'

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const aBaseItem : string = 'Programm-Sprache';
      cSepSYSTEM_MENU = wm_user + 100;
      cScanCompSystemMenu = wm_user + 101;
      cLANGMENU = wm_user + 102;
      SC_ITEM = $FF00;
var
  MenuItemInfo: TMenuItemInfo;
  PopupMenu: HMENU;
  Result: Boolean;
  SysMenu: HMenu;
  iPos, NumItems : Integer;
  wTemp1, wtemp2 : string;
  Buffer: array[0..79] of Char;
begin
  {Create the popup menu}
  PopupMenu := CreatePopupMenu;
  {Insert an item into it}
  for iPos := 5 downto 0 do
  begin
    FillChar(MenuItemInfo, SizeOf(MenuItemInfo), iPos);
      with MenuItemInfo do
      begin
        cbSize := SizeOf(MenuItemInfo);
        fMask := MIIM_TYPE or MIIM_ID;
        fType := MFT_STRING;
        wID := SC_ITEM + iPos;
        dwTypeData := PChar(inttostr(iPos));
        cch := Length(dwTypeData) * 2 + 2; //4; {'Item' is 4 chars}
      end;
    Result := InsertMenuItem(PopupMenu, 0, True, MenuItemInfo);
    Assert(Result, 'InsertMenuItem failed');
  end;

  SysMenu := GetSystemMenu(Handle, False);
  //why this isn't working???
  if not DeleteMenu(SysMenu, cLANGMENU, MF_BYCOMMAND) then
   begin
     ShowMessage('System Error Message: '+ SysErrorMessage(GetLastError)) ;
     //error message is - operation completed succesfully
   end;

  {Insert the popup into the system menu}
  FillChar(MenuItemInfo, SizeOf(MenuItemInfo), 0);
  with MenuItemInfo do
  begin
    cbSize := SizeOf(MenuItemInfo);
    fMask := MIIM_SUBMENU or MIIM_TYPE or MIIM_ID;
    fType := MFT_STRING;
    hSubMenu := PopupMenu;
    wId := cLANGMENU;
    dwTypeData :=  PChar('Test');//Before editing the question it was Program Language
    cch := Length(dwTypeData) * 2 + 2; //7; {'SubMenu' is 7 chars}
  end;

  Assert(SysMenu <> 0);
  Result := InsertMenuItem(SysMenu, GetMenuItemCount(SysMenu), True, MenuItemInfo);
  Assert(Result, 'InsertMenuItem failed');


      SysMenu := GetSystemMenu(Handle, False);
  //delete menu if exists - this is working
  DeleteMenu(SysMenu,cSepSYSTEM_MENU,MF_SEPARATOR);
  DeleteMenu(SysMenu,cScanCompSystemMenu,MFT_STRING);
  //add new ones
  InsertMenu(SysMenu, Word(-1), MF_SEPARATOR, cSepSYSTEM_MENU, '');
  FillChar(MenuItemInfo, SizeOf(TMenuItemInfo), #0);
  with MenuItemInfo do
   begin
   cbSize := SizeOf(TMenuItemInfo);
    fMask := MIIM_TYPE or MIIM_ID or MIIM_STATE;
    fType := MFT_STRING;
    wId := cScanCompSystemMenu;
    dwTypeData := PChar('Scan components');
    cch := Length('Scan components');
   end;
  Result := InsertMenuItem(SysMenu, GetMenuItemCount(SysMenu), True, MenuItemInfo);
  Assert(Result, 'InsertMenuItem failed');
end;
```

LE: This code is run several times, so I need to delete the items added each time.
LE2: Even this code is wrote in Delphi(Object Pascal), it calls WinApi functions from Windows. Maybe someone who has worked intensive with this and is a C/C++ programmer could help.

Comment: You appear to be deleting the item before you've added it. Why would you expect the menu with ID cLANGMENU to be present before you add it? And why would cLANGMENU be related to WM_USER? It's not a message ID.

Comment: @David Heffernan - indeed, first time is trying to delete a non-existing menu. it is related to WM_USER when the message is catch on the click event(this can be changed to another id $FF00 for example). The problem is, that I can not delete this submenu from the system menu. This code must run several times, so I need to delete this submenu, and insert it again with different values.

Comment: If you pass `True` as the second parameter of `GetSystemMenu`, then you don't have to bother with deleting any menu items. The OS will give you a handle to a fresh menu, and then you can just *add* the items you want instead of trying to delete the ones you don't.

Comment: You forgot MIIM_ID flag for your submenu item:

{Insert the popup into the system menu}
FillChar(MenuItemInfo, SizeOf(MenuItemInfo), 0);
  with MenuItemInfo do
  begin
    cbSize := SizeOf(MenuItemInfo);
    fMask := MIIM_SUBMENU or MIIM_TYPE or MIIM_ID;
    fType := MFT_STRING;
    hSubMenu := PopupMenu;
    wId := cLANGMENU;
    dwTypeData :=  PChar('Test');//Before editing the question it was Program Language
    cch := Length(dwTypeData) * 2 + 2; //7; {'SubMenu' is 7 chars}
  end;

Comment: So, including 'MIIM_ID' to 'fMask' doesn't solve your original issue? Weird, with my tests the submenu was successfully deleted.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz - I have followed suggestions from answers. See my answer to the question. MIIM_ID is needed only to have that ID received as a message on the WMCommand. Can you post the code which was deleting the submenu? And also which Delphi version/OS. Thank you

Comment: @RBA - The only thing I changed was to add the 'MIIM_ID' flag to fMask of MenuItemInfo for the 'test' menu per Rob's answer. D2007 on W7 64bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answers from Rob Kennedy and David Heffernan, I solved it. Solution is not to delete the menu item, is to get a new fresh handle of the system menu. Code bellow:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const 
      cSepSYSTEM_MENU = wm_user + 100;
      cScanCompSystemMenu = wm_user + 101;
      cLANGMENU = 65444;
      SC_ITEM = $FF00;
var
  MenuItemInfo: TMenuItemInfo;
  PopupMenu: HMENU;
  Result: Boolean;
  SysMenu: HMenu;
  iPos, NumItems : Integer;
  wTemp1, wtemp2 : string;
  Buffer: array[0..79] of Char;
  subMenu : HMENU;
begin

  SysMenu := GetSystemMenu(Handle, True);
  SysMenu := GetSystemMenu(Handle, False);

  //add new ones
  InsertMenu(SysMenu, Word(-1), MF_SEPARATOR, cSepSYSTEM_MENU, '');
  FillChar(MenuItemInfo, SizeOf(TMenuItemInfo), #0);
  with MenuItemInfo do
   begin
   cbSize := SizeOf(TMenuItemInfo);
    fMask := MIIM_TYPE or MIIM_ID or MIIM_STATE;
    fType := MFT_STRING;
    wId := cScanCompSystemMenu;
    dwTypeData := PChar('Scan components');
    cch := Length('Scan components');
   end;
  Result := InsertMenuItem(SysMenu, GetMenuItemCount(SysMenu), True, MenuItemInfo);
  Assert(Result, 'InsertMenuItem failed');

  {Create the popup menu}
  PopupMenu := CreatePopupMenu;
  {Insert an item into it}
  for iPos := Random(10) downto 0 do
  begin
    FillChar(MenuItemInfo, SizeOf(MenuItemInfo), 0);
      with MenuItemInfo do
      begin
        cbSize := SizeOf(MenuItemInfo);
        fMask := MIIM_TYPE or MIIM_ID;
        fType := MFT_STRING;
        wID := SC_ITEM + iPos;
        dwTypeData := PChar(inttostr(iPos));
        cch := Length(dwTypeData) * 2 + 2; //4; {'Item' is 4 chars}
      end;
    Result := InsertMenuItem(PopupMenu, 0, True, MenuItemInfo);
    Assert(Result, 'InsertMenuItem failed');
  end;

  FillChar(MenuItemInfo, SizeOf(MenuItemInfo), 0);
  with MenuItemInfo do

  begin
    cbSize := SizeOf(MenuItemInfo);
    fMask := MIIM_SUBMENU or MIIM_TYPE;
    fType := MFT_STRING;
    hSubMenu := PopupMenu;
    wId := cLANGMENU;
    dwTypeData :=  PChar('Programm-Language');
    cch := Length(dwTypeData) * 2 + 2; //7; {'SubMenu' is 7 chars}
  end;

  Assert(SysMenu <> 0);
  Result := InsertMenuItem(SysMenu, GetMenuItemCount(SysMenu), True, MenuItemInfo);
  Assert(Result, 'InsertMenuItem failed');
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647578.aspx) indicates that you need to set the `miim_ID` flag to use `wID`. Without it, the OS ignores that field, so the menu item you create doesn't get the ID value you specify. Thus, your further attempts to refer to that item by that ID fail.

You set that flag when you add the "Scan components" item, but you omit it for the "Test" item.

You could make it easier on yourself by calling `GetSystemMenu(Handle, True)`. That will reset the menu each time you call it, so you don't have to undo any prior customization.

Comment: chaging the code to   SysMenu := GetSystemMenu(Handle, True); gives an empty handle, so I can not add my item. For the "Program Language", I'm not a native English speaker, and I was doing this example focused on the problem I have. I will edit the question.

Comment: @RBA Please read the documentation for GetSystemMenu. Passing TRUE for revert does indeed result in NULL being returned. You need to follow up with a call passing FALSE in order to get a modifyable menu that has been reset.

Comment: Based on this answer and comments, I made a fully functional example. +1

Answer (score 1):

Delphi XE2 - clicking the button adds a `Program Language` system menu item each time and has no effect on `Scan components` although you say that it is removed for you.

I would suggest that it is because `Scan components` is a top-level menu item with no sub-menu, whereas `Program Language' has sub-menu items 0 -> 5.  I suspect that if you delete those first you should then be able to delete the parent menu (hmm, shouldn't it clean up it's own children?).

I am sorry, but I don't have time to code/verify this as I have a flight to catch and we seem to have different behaviours with different Delphi versions - but that is the difference between the two and what you should be looking at.

I wish that I could be of more help.

Comment: Thank you for trying. +1, and I will do further investigations on this.

Comment: Please update thw question as you discover anything and I will continue to try to help